# Is there any way in Reactor to limit the buffer used for backpressure?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new to Project Reactor and I'd like to find a way to limit the buffer size that is used to manage backpressure with the buffering strategy (which is the default).

Note that **I mean the buffer used to queue the publisher-generated items, not the downstream buffering**, see details below.

I have this simple example I'm playing with:

```java
@Test 
public void testColdFluxBlockingOnSubscriber ()
{
    int nitems = 50;
    
    long ct =   Flux.fromStream ( 
        IntStream.range ( 0,  nitems )
        .peek ( i -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux creating #{}", i ) )
        .boxed ()
    )
    .doOnSubscribe ( sub -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux subscribed" ) )
    .parallel ()
    .runOn ( Schedulers.newBoundedElastic ( DEFAULT_BOUNDED_ELASTIC_SIZE, 2, "fluxScheduler" ))
    .doOnNext ( i -> { 
        sneak ().run ( () -> Thread.sleep ( 500 ) ); // Emulates processing time
        log.info ( "SimpleFlux, thread: {}, element: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i );
    })
    .sequential ( 1 )
    .doOnComplete ( () -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux ended" ) )
    .count ()
    .block ();
    
    assertEquals ( nitems, ct, "SimpleFlux, bad count!" );      
}
```

As you can see, I process the original items in parallel mode, and I've added limits to such parallelism (in `parallel()`, `runOn()`, `sequential()`, as suggested by @oleh-dokuka.

However this doesn't work as I wish, for **the publisher-generated items appears to be stashed in a unbounded buffer, before they can be processed downstream.**

In fact, when I run it, first I see all of the item-creating messages, "SimpleFlux creating #NN", then all the subscriber messages, like
"SimpleFlux, thread: parallel-2, element: 7".

I understand that, while the consumer is sleeping, the stream-generated items are buffered and the original flow of items is never blocked, as the documentation says (see the [end of 4.4.2 here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create)).

I'd like to be able to control **the original flow**, i.e., to use a buffer like a blocking queue or a circular buffer, which should stop the flow source when the buffer is full and the subscriber hasn't consumed it yet.

This need is very common in situations where the subscriber does slow operations like I/O, while the data source streams items much faster.

Maybe I'm getting something wrong, but in my understanding, **limiting the downstream processing actually makes things worse in this scenario**.

Is this possible in Reactor? Is it possible without me having to add too much custom code (e.g., a semaphore)?

Am I missing something basic about Reactor or reactive programming? Given the feedback this question got, I'm suspecting that.

Comment: why are you running I/O operations in parallel and not async?

Comment: @Toerktumlare They're in parallel and therefore async, aren't they? I just want to test the case where the source is sequential and its processing is parallel, due to the fact the latter is much slower. I didn't try an all-sequential flux, but looks like it would be the same.

Comment: async and parallel is two different things, parallel is multiple threads for each request, async is one request handling multiple I/O at the same time. Parallel is good for heavy CPU tasks, since you want multiple core computing power. I/O doesn't need CPU power, so if you are doing that type of work, remove everything parallel, and let reactor handle the threading for you. Thats why you have an async lib, to avoid handing threading

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I don't think this is very relevant to the problem I've described: if the subscriber task is much slower than the spurce stream, then an unbounded buffer is filled, no matter if the input is processed sequentially, in parallel, by a CPU or an external resource that puts the subscriber on sleep. If you want, think that the sleep() above simulates some CPU-hungry task (after all, it's jut a toy example), the problem is the input buffer could grow to a memory overflow. And I don't get how I can let Reactor dealing with it, if you can make an example in an answer, many thanks.

Comment: i am not answering your question, im writing a comment, and no im not going to make any examples, good luck

Comment: The code example doesn't make much sense for Reactor, since you don't use any of the actual processing methods so it's unclear what you're measuring. I suggest to test with something looking more like a real code (ex., don't rely on `doOnNext`). But in general, Reactor wouldn't use a buffer unless you asked for it.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov it's not a real test, it's just showing some output that I manually test, so to speak. I put it into a test with the idea to add some verification later, there is already a test of count() anyway. By default, Reactor uses a buffering strategy to deal with backpressure, and my problem is that such buffering is unbounded. Maybe you're confusing this with Flux.buffer(), which batches the original input into chunks, that's a very different thing.

Comment: I mean, you wouldn't use `doOnNext` for long time processing in a real world code and I don't think it does what you want. I understand that Reactor may use a buffer, but usually for other things, it's not a necessary part of a backpressure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Project Reactor offers automatic backpressure support

Overall project reactor has defaults in the places where you may need to applies backpressure. So an average developer does not have to think much about it.

## When backpressure is needed?

Lets consider the following sample:

```java
Flux.fromStream ( 
            IntStream.range ( 0,  nitems )
            .peek ( i -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux creating #{}", i ) )
            .boxed ()
        )
        .doOnSubscribe ( sub -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux subscribed" ) )
        .doOnNext ( i -> { 
            sneak ().run ( () -> Thread.sleep ( 500 ) ); // Emulates processing time
            log.info ( "SimpleFlux, thread: {}, element: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i );
        })
        .doOnComplete ( () -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux ended" ) )
        .count ()
        .block ();
```

Do you think we need backpreasure on the sample above?
The answer is - not, we don't.

But you may wonder why? If we run that sample and inspect logs we will notice that all the processing happens within the same thread. It means that the actor responsible for value generation will be naturally executing processing of the generated values so no need to do extra work for producer actor and consumer actor coordination.

> Note, that is why when your processing happens on the same thread and there are no async operations which may explicitly or implicitly change execution thread.

Therefore, we may conclude that we need backpressure only in case when we have a producer and a consumer running on different actors (in java that could be Thread).

Overall, when you work with I/O operations you need to deal with backpressure, although reactor-natty and similar reactive frameworks implements that support out of the box and the demand is naturally being propagated through the chain.

## Can an operator introduce async boundary?

Yes, some operators may split execution of the producer and consumer so they run on different Threads.

For example, the obvious operator is `publishOn(Scheduler)` which makes the downstream elements processing happening on a different `Scheduler.Worker`. To make such value processing efficient and ensure [serial](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/tree/v1.0.4#term_serially) value processing we add a [small buffer](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.java#L7546) (by default 256 values could be buffered in it) which store values so then the other worker drain them and propagate for downstream processing.

There are more operators which may do the same, although they do that not that obviously:

1. `Flux.flatMap` / `.concatMap` / `switchMap` - flatten an external async process back into the main pipeline. Since the response signal may be delivered later, non-blocking implementation of those operators naturally propagate the result on the given carrier. Thus, producer starts being independent from consumer.
2. `Flux.zip` / `.combineLatest` / `.merge` / `.concat` / `.fristWithSignal` - there is a group of operators designed to combine multiple sources together, they have to implement coordination algorithm so all the sources produces same amount of elements. All of the has buffered
3. Any operator which has `int prefetch` parameter - there are much more operators which do async things, we can name all of them, although all of them has same configuration property called `prefetch`

## So, how to configure backpressure in the original sample?

```java
@Test 
    public void testColdFluxBlockingOnSubscriber ()
    {
        int nitems = 50;
        
        long ct =   Flux.fromStream ( 
            IntStream.range ( 0,  nitems )
            .peek ( i -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux creating #{}", i ) )
            .boxed ()
        )
        .doOnSubscribe ( sub -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux subscribed" ) )
        .parallel () <---- backpressure could be configured 
        .runOn ( Schedulers.parallel () ) <---- obvious thread switch, backpressure can be configured 
        .doOnNext ( i -> { 
            sneak ().run ( () -> Thread.sleep ( 500 ) ); // Emulates processing time
            log.info ( "SimpleFlux, thread: {}, element: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i );
        })
        .sequential () <----- operator that gathers parallel result signals and serialises them, backpressure could be configured 
        .doOnComplete ( () -> log.info ( "SimpleFlux ended" ) )
        .count ()
        .block ();
        
        assertEquals ( nitems, ct, "SimpleFlux, bad count!" );      
    }
```

There are 3 places where we may need backpressure, all of those operators are commented and all of them has `prefetch` property:

1. `Flux.parallel` - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel-int-int-
2. `ParallelFlux.runOn` - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux.html#runOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-int-
3. `ParallelFlux.sequentual` - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ParallelFlux.html#sequential-int-

Comment: thank you very much, I tried to limit parallelism as you suggest, but the problem is in the original flow, I've also tried to explain what I mean better, please see above. And no, I'm not asking how to control backpressure downstream, but if and how to block the original flow, and if that even makes sense in Reactor.

Comment: Did some more tests, and I think i got it! The flow generator/publisher throughput is indirectly controlled by downstream limits on parallelism and the like. Thanks again!